# Jquery/Javascript : call a function outside of the file we are calling the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a number of javascript plugins which are included in my HTML file, and are included successfully because I have checked. 
Heres the problem;
Basically I want to create a function **outside** the HTML file, and then **inside** the HTML file load that particular function when the document is ready.

this is the function (outside) of the HTML file. As a stand alone JS file:

```
function do_anchor_scrolling() {
    $('#back_to_top').anchorScroll();
    $("#landing_link").anchorScroll();
    $("#menu_link").anchorScroll();
    $("#sauces_link").anchorScroll();
    $("#ranches_link").anchorScroll();
    $("#order_link").anchorScroll();
    $("#about_link").anchorScroll();
    $("#franchise_link").anchorScroll();
});
```

the function is called `do_anchor_scrolling`

How in JQuery can I say when the document is ready perform the `do_anchor_scrolling` function.

Comment: `$(function() { do_anchor_scrolling(); });` if the function is loaded and is in the right scope of course.

Comment: Enclose in $(function() {})  handler.. Make sure you include the other file before this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the document is ready, call the function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    do_anchor_scrolling();
});
```

Comment: the error was actually how I was writing the function in the other file. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a handler into the [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method:

```
$(document).ready(do_anchor_scrolling);
```

Or even shorter:

```
$(do_anchor_scrolling);
```

Notice the function is not executed right there (no invoking parenthesis) - the function object itself is passed into the `ready` function.

Answer (score -1):

You can just do:

```
$.getScript("yourfile.js");//it grabs and executes yourfile.js
                           //so your function is now defined
do_anchor_scrolling();     //and you can call it
```

You can go without the `$_getScript()` call by just putting `yourfile.js` inside a `<script>` tag in `<head>`.

Comment: I have added the file in the head of the html (which of course has to be done). For now I have just made the function a simple alert. However nothing is happening.

Comment: Then you probably have an error somewhere, check the console for possible runtime errors..